# Drag-drop from NSTableView to NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I need to drag a row from NSTableView containing an image path and drop it over NSImageView, and the image of the dragged row should appear in the imageview. Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your [table data source](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/), implement the necessary methods for table row dragging. You'll put data representing the row onto the drag pasteboard in one or more data types. One type you'll use for this is `NSFilenamesPboardType`, which takes an array of pathnames.

Then, make a subclass of NSImageView that can handle `NSFilenamesPboardType` in drops. (You'll need to implement methods from [the NSDraggingDestination informal protocol](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingDestination_Protocol/).) Then make your image view an instance of this subclass, instead of NSImageView, and [register](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/registerForDraggedTypes:) that view for `NSFilenamesPboardType`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot. It really worked. I registered NSImageView and NSTableView for NSStringPboardType and NSFilenamesPboardType. Then in TableView delegate I used
the following code.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard
{
    NSString *string = [filePath objectAtIndex:[rowIndexes firstIndex]];
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:self];
    [pboard setString:string forType:NSStringPboardType];
    return YES;
}
```

And in NSImageView  NSDragging Destination informal protocol, used following code.

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSString *str = [[sender draggingPasteboard] stringForType:NSStringPboardType];
    myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str];
    [self setImage:myImage];
    [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}
```

cheers :)

Comment: You only have to register the receiving view (the image view), not the sending view (the table view), for the dragged type. Unless you want to allow dropping on the table view as well—but that requires more data source methods.

Comment: Also, don't forget to release what you have allocked. See the Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/

Comment: Yes. you are right. I'll implement it.

Thanks a lot once again. :)